# Highlight Date Value but not when it is NULL

Tags: birt

Under Property Editor in the Highlights tab I have used this syntax:

```
1 Less than or Equal BirtDateTime.diffDay(row["GEN_SAFETY"],BirtDateTime.today())
```

Background color is set to GREEN, but I don't want a highlight if the date is NULL.

How can I accomplish that in the syntax?

Comment: what do you mean by property editor? Are you talking about some javascript UI framework?

Comment: This is BIRT made by eclipse from what I can make of it

Comment: Exactly. A BIRT tool called Plataeu Report Designer.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but could you not just set your highlight background to white if the value is null?

Comment: 760 Less than or Equal BirtDateTime.diffDay(row["GEN_SAFETY",BirtDateTime())  Condition is set to Blue highlight, can't set condition to white if NULL usinmg Property Editor on Birt

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Plateau Report Designer.  In BIRT, it's pretty straightforward.  In the Property Editor, you have a Highlight tab, and you add your highlight and set your conditions.

If I'm understanding your question:

You have your background set to green by default.

If your GEN_SAFETY field is today or before, you want it blue.

If there is no date, you want it white.

---

So you would add two highlights.

The first you already have.

The second would be something along the lines of:

[image]